# Как разбить строку по пробелам?

Tags: c++

Как разбить строку на символ - '\n' вместо пробелов?

Нашел решение только с символьной строкой:

```
char text[256] = { "Welcome to my home!" };
for (int i = 0; i < string(text).size() - 1; i++) {
    if (text[i] == ' ') {
        text[i] = '\n';
    }
}
cout << text << endl;
return 0;
```

Неужели нету решения с строкой(string) ? Жду ваших вариантов.

Comment: А вы просто попробуйте тот же код, но с `std::string text`. Вдруг он тоже работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string s("Welcome to my home!");
s.replace(s.begin(), s.end(), ' ', '\n');
```